# how to add hypen in date (without delimiters)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've date and time values without delimiters like,

```
$date = "20150206";
$time = "011526";
```

How to do I convert it to date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use simple date function for this purpose

```
<?php echo date("Y-d-m",strtotime($date)); ?>
<?php echo date("h:i:s",strtotime($time)); ?>
```

Comment: may be second one `$time`

Answer (score 2):

Try [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)  require (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

```
//$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '20150206011526');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $date.$time);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date.$time));
```

change the format according to your given date format

Comment: Can i include any library file to my code for this function?
I got this error.

Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: require (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) may be you have lower version

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple method.

```
$datetime = strtotime($date.$time); 
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $datetime);
```